# ¿Por que no inserta los datos en la base de datos?

Tags: php, javascript, sql

estoy tratando de guardar datos usando php y javascript(mediante jquery) pero no funciona,la idea es insertar dos campos con datos en la BD, revise la consola del navegador y no me sale ningún error por lo que no se que estoy haciendo mal, les dejo el código, muchas gracias por sus respuestas

Este es el archivo de Conexión que estoy utilizando

```
<?php

class Conexion{
var $conexion;
  function Conexion(){
     //conectarse
$this->conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","crud");

  }
 }
?>
```

archivo index

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#Ingresar").click(function(){
     var parametros = {
     "nombre_rol" : $("#nombre_rol").val(),
     "descripcion" : $("#descripcion").val(),
     "operacion":"insertar"
     }
  $.ajax({
         data:  parametros,
         url:   'controlador.php',
         type:  'post',
         async: false,
         beforeSend: function (){
            alert("datos ingresados");
        },

      });
   });

  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Main content -->
 <section class="content">
        <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Roles</h3>
            </div>
      <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                <form id="incidentesf" name="incidentesf">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nombre del Rol</label>
                        <input type="text" id="nombre_rol" name="nombre_rol" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Descripcion del Rol</label>
                        <input type="text" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                    </form>
                <div class="col-md-1" style="top: 25px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="Ingresar" name="Ingresar" >Ingresar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Controlador mi idea es que este archivo reciba los datos que estoy enviando para que luego los pase al modelo y se ejecute la consulta para guardar los datos

```
<?php
include_once "modelo.php";
$objeto=new Roles();

switch($_POST["operacion"]){

    case 'insertar':

    $objeto->$nombre_rol=$_POST["$nombre_rol"];
    $objeto->$descripcion=$_POST["$descripcion"]
    $objeto->insertar();
    break;
  }

  ?>
```

Modelo, la tabla tiene un ID auto incrementable por eso no lo añadi

```
 <?php

 include_once'conexion.php';

 class Roles extends Conexion{

 var $nombre_rol;
 var $descripcion;

 function Roles(){
  $this->Conexion();
 }
function insertar(){
$nombre_rol=$this->$nombre_rol;
$descripcion=$this->$descripcion;
$sql="INSERT INTO roles VALUES('','$nombre_rol','$descripcion')";
$resultado=mysqli_query($this->conexion,$sql);

 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

El error podría deberse a que estás usando `$` para recuperar los datos de `$_POST` esta parte:

```
$objeto->$nombre_rol=$_POST["$nombre_rol"];
$objeto->$descripcion=$_POST["$descripcion"]
```

Deberías usar los nombres de cada clave, si usas `$` PHP interpretará que intentas usar el valor de variables:

```
$objeto->$nombre_rol=$_POST["nombre_rol"];
$objeto->$descripcion=$_POST["descripcion"]
```

De todos modos, no estoy seguro que funcione. Tu código necesita ser revisado a profundidad. Tienes muchos errores de lógica, como áreas absolutamente abandonadas en las que ante un fallo no habrá respuesta.

Tienes también código antiguo (por ejemplo en PHP ya `var` no se usa para los miembros de las clases. Deberías también revisar el modelo de datos (por ejemplo `Rol` no debería extender de `Conexion`, eso es un error de diseño a nivel de clases, pero ese es otro tema).

El manejo de objetos tampoco es claro. Por ejemplo, sin `Rol` ya tiene propiedades `$nombre_rol` y `$descripcion` sería mejor informar a la clase mediante un constructor, no asignando los datos directamente con esto: `$objeto->$nombre_rol=$nombre_rol;` Si dotas a la clase de un constructor harías algo así: `$objeto=new Rol($nombre_rol, $descripcion);`

En la parte de Ajax el código tampoco es del todo dichoso. No tiene mucho sentido tu `async: false,` ... es mejor dotar a la petición Ajax de sus funciones `done` y `fail` para controlar la respuesta correcta de la petición o sus fallos. Ahí también tienes código obsoleto: `document.ready` es obsoleto desde jQuery 3, `type`  también es parte del las primeras versiones de jQuery (aunque todo eso funcione ahora es mejor usar código actualizado porque muchas de esas cosas quedarán fuera de jQuery 4).

En fin, son muchas cosas...

Aplicando un poco parte de lo dicho, te propongo esto. Muchas modificaciones no las he hecho porque se trataría de cambiar tu modelo de datos y eso ya es asunto tuyo.

> **Otra cosa IMPORTANTE es que tu código es vulnerable a ataques de
>   *Inyección SQL*. Deberías usar consultas preparadas para evitar ese riesgo.**

Y, finalmente, ya que estás implementando una arquitectura orientada a objetos, no tiene sentido que para mysqli uses el estilo procedural, cuando esta API tiene una estilo orientado a objetos que además es más claro y más moderno.

Bueno ya no te pongo la cabeza como un bombo :-) ... Esta es mi propuesta para empezar a mejorar tu código y hacerlo funcionar.

### Javascript/jQuery

Todo debe ir dentro del bloque `$( function() {`

```
/* 
    *Se recomienda function() en lugar de document.ready
    *ya que éste es obsoleto desde jQuery 3
*/
$( function() { 
    $("#Ingresar").click(function(e) {
        /*Impide que se recargue la página al enviar*/
        e.preventDefault();
        /* 
            No hace falta poner comillas a los valores de la izquierda
            son nombres de clave del objeto
        */
        var parametros = 
            {
                nombre_rol: $("#nombre_rol").val(),
                descripcion : $("#descripcion").val(),
                operacion:"insertar"
            };

        var mAjax = $.ajax({
            url: 'controlador.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: parametros, 
            dataType: 'json'   //Generalmente se usa json por su facilidad
        });
        /*
            Conviene otorgar una función done a nuestras peticiones Ajax
            Aquí se controlará la respuesta cuando ésta sea exitosa
        */
        mAjax.done(function(outPut) {
            /*
                Este manejo debe ser acorde con dos cosas:
                 1. Con dataType, indicado más arriba
                 2. Con la respuesta del servidor
                 Dado que indicamos que era un JSON, verás que desde el servidor 
                 devolveremos un JSON. Es el formato más adecuado, porque nos permite
                 con facilidad verificar si hay una clave error por ejemplo
            */

            /*
                Esto es sólo para prueba, no olvides borrarlos
            */
            console.log(outPut);
            /*
                Aquí vamos a verificar si hay error o no
            */
            if (outPut.error) {
                /*
                    En PHP pusimos una clave error en todas las partes donde hubo fallo
                */
                console.log(outPut.error);
            }else{
                /*
                    En PHP pusimos una clave done en todas las partes que hubo éxito
                */
                console.log(outPut.done);
            }


        });
        /*
            Conviene otorgar también función fail a nuestras peticiones Ajax
            Aquí se controlará la respuesta cuando ésta falle
            OJO: aquí fail se refiere a fallos de red u otros, no a fallos de lógica
        */

        mAjax.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Error en la petición: " + textStatus);
        });

    });

});
```

### PHP

Esta es la parte donde recibes el POST.

```
/*
    La idea es que tu código debe estar CONTROLADO
    en todas las eventualidades posibles, hasta el más mínimo detalle
    Los controles que estableceremos a este nivel serán:
      1. Que hay una clave operacion con datos en el POST
      2. En el caso de "insertar" verificamos que nombre_rol y descripcion tienen datos
      3. Haremos que la llamada a insertar() devuelva correcto o error
      4. En los else emitiremos un array con una clave "error"
      Todo se recogerá en una variable $outPut 
      que será lo que imprimiremos al final en forma de JSON
      por lo que expliqué del dataType en la parte de Ajax...
      Todo esto va a permitir informar de cualquier cosa que ocurra
      Cuando trabajas con código cliente/servidor no deberías dejar vacíos,
      partes mudas del código que se falla no ocurre nada
*/  
include_once "modelo.php";
$objeto=new Roles();
$operacion=!empty($_POST["operacion"]) ? $_POST["operacion"] : NULL;
if ($operacion){
    switch($$operacion){

        case 'insertar':
            $nombre_rol=!empty($_POST["nombre_rol"]) ? $_POST["nombre_rol"] : NULL;
            $descripcion=!empty($_POST["descripcion"]) ? $_POST["descripcion"] : NULL;
            if ($nombre_rol && $descripcion) {
                $objeto->$nombre_rol=$nombre_rol;
                $objeto->$descripcion=$descripcion;
                $outPut=$objeto->insertar();
            }else{
                $outPut=array("error"=>"Datos nulos para insertar");
            }
            break;
      }
}else{
    $outPut=array("error"=>"Operación no válida en el POST");   
}
echo json_encode($outPut);
```

#### Clase `Roles`

```
include_once'conexion.php';

class Roles extends Conexion {

    var $nombre_rol;
    var $descripcion;

    function Roles(){
        $this->Conexion();
    }

    function insertar(){
        $nombre_rol=$this->$nombre_rol;
        $descripcion=$this->$descripcion;
        $sql="INSERT INTO roles VALUES('','$nombre_rol','$descripcion')";
        if (!$resultado=mysqli_query($this->conexion,$sql)){
            $outPut=array("error"=>"Ocurrió un error en la inserción");
        } else {
            $outPut=array("done"=>"Filas insertadas: ".mysqli_affected_rows($this->conexion));
        }
        return $outPut;
    }
}
```

Comment: Michas gracias por tu respuesta, quiero mejorar en lo que es programación, y mencionaste muchas cosas que no sabia, gracias :D